# Sufficient Statistic

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

I have a question:

> Does a sufficient statistic have to be one to one? For example, can $T(x) = x^2$ or $T(x) = |x|$ be sufficient statistics? I know that one to one functions of sufficient statistics are sufficient.

Comment: **Hint**: Can you think of an example where this is the case, say, in the context of a family of normal distributions? How would you prove it?

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't have to be one-to-one.  Consider a distribution family with pmf

$$f(x \mid \theta) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{with probability 0.5 if } \theta=0 \\
1 & \text{with probability 0.5 if } \theta=0 \\
2 & \text{with probability 0.5 if } \theta=1 \\
3 & \text{with probability 0.5 if } \theta=1 \\
\end{cases}$$

Then, the sufficient statistic for $x$ is $\left\lfloor\frac x2\right\rfloor$.

The way I think of sufficient statistics is that they tell you what you learned from $x$ to identify $\theta$.

When you don't use all of the information in a single observation $x$, that is, if there exists two outcomes $\omega_1, \omega_2$ such that $T(\omega_1) = T(\omega_2)$, then there is no way to alter the parameters $\theta$ of the distribution to change the relative probabilities $f(\omega_1 \mid \theta) / f(\omega_2 \mid \theta)$ of the two outcomes.

Comment: (+1) Good example. It might be slightly unconventional in the sense that from the sufficient statistic in this example, one can recover *perfect* knowledge of the parameter of interest. It might be helpful to have a second one that uses precisely the proposed statistic that the OP gives, as well.

Comment: @cardinal: Good point.  Do you think that would be a good exercise for the OP?

Comment: Yes, I think it would make a good exercise. If it's ok, allow me to quibble just a little bit with your last sentence. Usually the point of sufficient is *precisely* because we *don't* want to use all of the information in $x$. In other words, in a multiple-observation scenario, the vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is *always* sufficient, but we'd rather use some function $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^k$ of the vector that maps it down to a smaller space (i.e., $k < n$) without losing information about the parameter. :)

Comment: @cardinal:  You're right.  I was trying to make a point about when you have a single observation $x$.

Comment: @cardinal: I think I should probably quibble about your quibble though:  Usually, $T$ is defined from the sample space to a vector of reals (e.g., $T: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^k$), and the mapping down to a smaller sample for exponential families is accomplished by finding $E(T(x))$ for $x \in \{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$.  (Taking that expectation is almost never one-to-one.)

Comment: Hi Neil. I suspect this just may be a notation and/or terminology difference. When I spoke of $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^s$, then I was thinking of the sufficient statistic corresponding to the *sample* $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and not a single variable within the sample. This is, I believe, the usual notion of $T$ since that is what we're normally concerned with (reducing the data without losing information). In the case of the exponential family we get that the sufficient statistic is coordinate-wise *linear* in the sufficient statistics, so the data reduction is independent of the sample size.

Comment: But, this is just a fortuitous consequence of the structure of the exponential family. This mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^k$, linear in each coordinate, of course, cannot be bijective for $n > k$. (I was not quite sure what point you were making regarding the expected value.)

Comment: My $\mathbb R^k$ became an $\mathbb R^s$ by accident (somehow) in one place. I suspect you were able to decode that, though. :)

Comment: @cardinal: I think we agree on the facts :)  Although, I've always seen $T(x)$ as part of the definition of the exponential family $f(x) \propto \exp(T(x) \cdot \theta)$.  (E.g., http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~nielsen/MEF/)  This is also the notation that the question-asker is using…

Comment: Neil, my choice of $T$ was suggestive, but, perhaps unfortunate as it seems to have obscured the point I was attempting to make. My $T$ has nothing to do directly with the exponential family; it is simply a *completely general* sufficient statistic of a sample of size $n$. So, in the case of an exponential family of full rank $k$, my $T$ can be of the form that has coordinates that are sums of the $T$ you've used.

Answer (score 2):

I like Neil G's example. I wondered if we could find some simple conditions that would prohibit a sufficient statistics to be one-to-one. Here is my take on this.

(Following the comment by cardinal, in all that follows, suppose that $n\geq 2$.)

Suppose that we have the usual setup: the random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are conditionaly i.i.d., given $\Theta=\theta$, with some density $f_{X_i\mid\Theta}(x_i\mid\theta)$.

As pointed out by cardinal, the identity map $\mathrm{id}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is always sufficient for the parameter $\Theta,$ and it is one-to-one. It is also easy to see that the order statistics $U:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $U(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x_{(1)},\dots,x_{(n)})$ is also sufficient, but it is not one-to-one. The intuitive idea is that the value of both carry the same information about $\Theta$ as the original sample $(x_1,\dots,x_n).$

We generally want our sufficient statistic $T$ to reduce the dimension of the original sample, and this reduction will, in general, as we can see from many of the usual examples, imply that $T$ is not one-to-one.

Now, remember that $T$ is $\textit{minimal}$ sufficient if it is sufficient, and for $\textit{any}$ other sufficient statistic $S,$ if $S(x)=S(y)$, then $T(x)=T(y)$, which means that $T$ is a function of every other sufficient statistic $S$. This definition captures the idea that, if $T$ is minimal sufficient, then you can't find another sufficient statistic that provides more data reduction than $T$ does.

**Proposition**. If $T$ is minimal sufficient, then $T$ is not one-to-one.

**Proof**. Suppose that $T$ is minimal sufficient and one-to-one. Let $U$ be the order statistics as defined above. Take a sample point $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, a permutation $\pi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and $y=(x_{\pi(1)},\dots,x_{\pi(n)}),$ such that $x\neq y$. It is clear that $U(x)=U(y)$ and, since $U$ is sufficient, we must have, by definition, that $T(x)=T(y)$, which contradicts the fact that $T$ is one-to-one.

Comment: You'll need at least some minor qualifiers. A bit tongue-in-cheek, admittedly, but, **counterexample**: Take $n = 1$.

Comment: Yeah! Just hacked your regularity condition.

Comment: (+1) This is nice. But, note that it depends on the assumption that $\mathbf X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ for $n \geq 2$ is a *random sample*, so we should probably state that explicitly (**Edit**: You did already.). In particular, if we have something like, say, certain generalized linear models (e.g., logistic), then it can turn out that $\mathbf X$ itself is minimal sufficient.

Comment: Also, if you use the usual definition of *minimal sufficiency*, i.e., $T$ is minimal sufficient if $T$ is sufficient and is a function of every other sufficient statistic, then the proof drops out immediately since $U$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: You're right. The shorter proof stresses the key point: since, in this model, $U$ is sufficent and $\textit{not}$ one-to-one, then the minimal sufficient $T$ can't be one-to-one either.

Comment: Hi Zen. I looked through several books I have handy, including some problem books and have not (yet) found any explicit mention of this. I like the problem a lot and will be keeping it in my quiver. Thanks for thinking about this and for this answer. Cheers. :)

Comment: You're welcome! I was thinking about it, and using essentially the same argument we can prove that, under appropriate conditions, a minimal sufficient $T$ is always a symmetric function of the data, in the sense that $T(x_1,\dots,x_n)=T(x_{\pi(1)},\dots,x_{\pi(n)})$, for every permutation $\pi$. And there we have another cool exercise!

Comment: That's true, though maybe it shouldn't seem too surprising, either. Indeed, anything that tells you something about a parameter in an iid framework had better not depend on the order in which you made the observations. I suppose one way to formalize this is to use the fact that it must be in the image of a function of the order statistics. :)

Comment: Keeping the iid framework, maybe a more general way to express the existing symmetry would be to prove something about the sigma-fields generated by a minimal sufficient $T$ and by the order statistics. I'll give it a try.